# Power Shell Invoke-Rest Version 2.0 Equivalent for posting a Json doc to a MongoHQ db

Tags: json, mongodb, rest, httprequest, powershell-2.0

Im building a Powershell script that connects out to our servers and grabs a bunch of event and print WMI object data. From there I'm creating .JSON files out of them and trying to send them to our MongoDB. Currently I have it working where it connects directly to the db just using a MongoDBDriver.dll however we want to do a rest call of sorts. In powerShell Version 3.0 I could do

Invoke-Rest -Uri https://api.mongohq.com/databases/PrintData/collections/MyCollection/documents?_apikey= ourAPIKey -ContentType application/json -Body $json -Method Post

pretty easily, however we most of our clients run 2.0 and it will be a nightmare trying to get them to update.

We have also gotten it to work by running a node.js server that accepts calls and curling our object to it, but once again it would be difficult to get our clients to put curl on their windows machines.

Any suggestions of a 2.0 cmdlet I'm missing or any other way to push a .JSON document to our MongoDB HQ would be great. Thanks

Comment: I figured this out. I ended up using a System.Net.WebRequest object, set the target url, set the method name, encode the json string, set the requestStream, and then getResponse and it works fine.

Comment: For the future, Mr. Bezek a shorter question title would get you more answers.  I was searching again to see if anyone wrote a mongohq powershell library and ran into this question.  Finally got around to implementing this solution...